# Python: Loop isn't waiting for user's input

Tags: python, function, loops, python-3.x, input

Normally when I do a input for the user, Python waits until they press the enter key. However in my script for some reason Python isn't waiting for an input and keeps printing the text...

`user_option()`, just has a few print statements in it...

If anyone could tell me how to make it so it will wait until the user enters an input that would be very much appreciated.

Code:

```
while True:
  user_option()
  decision = input("What coarse of action should I take?")
  decision = decision.strip().lower()
  if decision == "a":
    rehydration()
  elif decision == "b":
    moderate_speed()
  elif decision == "c":
    fast_speed()
  elif decision == "d":
    rest()
```

I'm running this with Python 3.4.

Comment: A screenshot of your code is not helpful. Paste your code - as text - into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in the input method. **In Python 3.x `raw_input()` does not exits and only `input()` exits.** But in older version `input()` and `raw_input()` exits. So according to your Python version use proper method. [See more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

In Python 3.x you can simulate `raw_input()` by using `eval(input())`

Comment: What Sawon says is true. Still since William is using 3.4 and input() correctly this couldnt be the answer, can it?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the proper way of grabbing input is

```
input = raw_input('prompt')
```